# UDP bad checksum errors

Tags: udp, sr-iov

UDP checksum can not be computed by Hardware virtualization (Intel 82599 SRIOV PCI pass-through, DPDK).

UDP bad checksum errors are observed in the TCP dump(pcap) collected after host on the Service router when the UDP checksum computation is Hardware offloaded. UDP checksum is set  to 0  and Hardware offloading is disabled to prevent the UDP checksum errors.

Is this the only way out?Please suggest.